# Publishing rss feed app to Appstore

Tags: ios, iphone, rss

I developed news app for iOS and now i am going to publish to app store.
The app receives each news from my own website that was built by me and the server get all news data with RSS feeds. I am afraid of these. Is it possible to publish on Appstore?
I have read app store review guideline Section 12.
In there, it wrotes like this.

12. Scraping and aggregation

12.1
Apps that scrape any information from Apple sites (for example from apple.com, iTunes Store, App Store, iTunes Connect, Apple Developer Programs, etc.) or create rankings using content from Apple sites and services will be rejected

12.2
Apps may use approved Apple RSS feeds such as the iTunes Store RSS feed

12.3
Apps that are simply web clippings, content aggregators, or a collection of links, may be rejected

But my app get all news data from own server, not scrapping and aggregation. Only server gets all news data with Rss feeds.
Is this also rejected? I am really afraid of this problem. Please teach me if anybody experienced.

Comment: No these rules only apply to the Apple sites. Since your app is using your server these rules do not apply. Accept for rule 12.3 which is alway applicable.

Answer (score 1):

As far as your app displays RSS from your own site , you do not need to worry about rejection of the app.

Yes, but you should not use any RSS from Apple's website or RSS from website which requires permission to use them.